# cant escape the backslash with regex in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, backslash

I'm trying to replace forbidden characters with space for filename. For this reason I put the forbidden characters in a regex then replaced them. It works good except backslash. Here a part of my code

`Input.search(/[<>:"/\\\\|?*]/g)` or `Input.search(/[<>:"/\\|?*]/g)` then `Input.replace(/[<>:"/\\\\|?*]/g, '')`or `Input.replace(/[<>:"/\\|?*]/g, '')` (I tried four backslash and double backslahsh)

It works only the inputs with double backslash
For example:
`input` = `example\\`
`response` = `example` but if I entered `"example\"` response = `Unexpected token \n`.

Also backslash colors looks different then other characters in the regex. Can anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: Please add the code you're having trouble with, and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions

Comment: I added code and give more detail thanks for advice